# Open source tool to extract text from developer file types

Tags: open-source, java, text-processing

I would like to parse the text content from these developer file types and index them and make them available for my lucene search engine for search.

I would like to parse the text content from these developer file types and index them and make them available for my lucene search engine for search.

> .1c .adoc .ahk .aj .al .ald .alf .applescript .armasm .as .asciidoc
>   .atom .au3 .bash .bat .bf .c .c++ .capnp .cc .ceylon .clj .cmd .coffee
>   .coffeescript .conf .cpp .cr .cs .cson .css .d .dart .delphi .diff
>   .dos .dst .dust .elm .erl .f90 .f95 .fs .glsl .gms .go .golo .gradle
>   .groovy .gsh .gvy .gy .h .h++ .haml .handlebars .haxe .hbs .hpp .hs
>   .hx .iced .ini .irb .irpf90 .java .js .json .jsp .lasso .less .lisp
>   .livescript .log .ls .lua .mak .md .mel .mk .mkd .mkdown .ml .mli .mm
>   .mma .nb .nc .nsi .nsis .objc .oxygene .pde .perl .php .php3 .php4
>   .php5 .php6 .pl .plist .profile .prop .properties .proto .py .rb .rbw
>   .rib .rs .rsl .rss .ruby .scad .scala .scm .scpt .scss .sh .sql .ss
>   .st .styl .swift .tex .thrift .ts .twig .typescript .v .vala .vb .vbs
>   .vim .xhtml .xml .xpath .xq .xsl .zsh

Can someone suggest me the available open source tools to parse text content from these file types ?

Comment: What do you mean by parse in this case? Do you mean extract the text from the files and perform operations with Java on that text? You can do that directly with Java itself, although I'd much rather use Python (3.x) for text parsing. Is it the indexing you're primarily concerned about?

Comment: Parse in this case I refer to reading the text content within these files. And I should be able to index them. And feed them for search engine (which is built with lucene) and make it available for search @Shule .

Comment: I'm confused as to what you need the software to do, and what you already have ways of doing.

Comment: I have a search engine (which is built with lucene) and i have to extract the text content from these files - to make them available for search @Shule